# Scala recursive parameters?

Tags: scala

Could you please tell me what is wrong with this Scala code?

```
package com.user.common

class Notification(message: String, next: Option[Notification]) {
  def write(): String = {
    message
  }

  def getAll(): Stream[Notification] = {
    next match {
      case Some(n) => Stream.cons(n, n.getAll())
      case None => Stream.empty
    }
  }
}

case class Email(msg: String)
  extends Notification(msg, None)

case class SMS(msg: String)
  extends Notification(msg, Option(Email))

case class VoiceRecording(msg: String)
  extends Notification(msg, Option(SMS))
```

The errors from compiler are as below.

```
[error] /common/Test.scala:15: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Some[A]
[error]  required: Option[com.user.common.Notification]
[error]       case Some(n) => Stream.cons(n, n.getAll())
[error]                ^
[error] /common/Test.scala:15: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : A
[error]  required: com.user.common.Notification
[error]       case Some(n) => Stream.cons(n, n.getAll())
[error]                                   ^
[error] /common/Test.scala:15: value getAll is not a member of type parameter A
[error]       case Some(n) => Stream.cons(n, n.getAll())
[error]                                        ^
[error] /common/Test.scala:25: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : com.user.common.Email.type
[error]  required: com.user.common.Notification
[error]   extends Notification(msg, Option(Email))
[error]                                    ^
[error] /common/Test.scala:28: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : com.user.common.SMS.type
[error]  required: com.user.common.Notification
[error]   extends Notification(msg, Option(SMS))
[error]                                    ^
[error] 5 errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

I could not understand the problem. Similarly, I have no idea how to restructure the code. My basic idea is to keep value of one case class and iterate over them until I reach to None. From top level case class until low level one.

Comment: `Option(Email)` and `Option(SMS)`. This is one of the problems.

Comment: Compiling the code you provided will not show the first 3 of those errors.

Comment: okay, I changed as @Matt suggested. However, there are still first three errors from compiler.

Comment: @Jasper-M, that is interesting! Maybe this because of some of my scalac flags.. Yes, it is because of -Xstrict-inference !

Comment: @morazow Your code, changed according to the suggestions of Matt, compiles just fine for me.

Comment: Thanks @Jasper-M, yes it was because of -Xstrict-inference compiler flag.

Comment: It seems the flag is not yet present in Scala 2.10.4 - what about explicitly widening the type as in ```Some( Email(msg) : Option[Notification])```?

Comment: @lambda.xy.x it did not work for me. fails with first error.
   found Some[A] required Option[Notification]

Answer (score 3):

```
case class SMS(msg: String)
  extends Notification(msg, Option(Email))

case class VoiceRecording(msg: String)
  extends Notification(msg, Option(SMS))`
```

In your second parameter, you are passing an option on a class type whereas an instance of the class is expected

Maybe what you want is

```
case class SMS(msg: String)
  extends Notification(msg, Option(Email(msg)))

case class VoiceRecording(msg: String)
  extends Notification(msg, Option(SMS(msg)))`
```

Comment: you can reproduce them by adding "-Xstrict-inference" to scalacOptions.